# How to wait for a process to be gone in chef (Windows)

Tags: windows, chef-infra, sysinternals

I would like to make sure chef waits if a process is still running before continuing. How to do that on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://discourse.chef.io/t/chef-client-wait-until-successful-ssh-connection-ruby-block/7519/2) a smart use of execute resource can be employed, i.e. to wait for TiWorker.exe process to complete before continuing:

```
execute "Wait until TiWorker is not present" do
   command "c:/Sysinternals/pslist /accepteula TiWorker"
   retries 30
   returns 1
   retry_delay 10
   timeout 10
end
```

where pslist is [pslist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pslist.aspx)